# Connection to Mi Band 3 is impossible

Tags: python, xiaomi, gatttool

I'm trying to connect to Mi Band 3 via Python using some libraries that I got and I cannot - bluepy returns such error:

```
bluepy.btle.BTLEDisconnectError: Failed to connect to peripheral EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B, addr type: random
```

I tried to connect to the device also using gatttool and there's also some problem that I don't understand:

```
[EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B
Error: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)
[EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B][LE]> 
[EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B
[EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B][LE]> primary
Command Failed: Disconnected
Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)
[EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B][LE]> 
[EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B
Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)
[EC:E7:23:1D:01:9B][LE]>
```

Maybe anyone of you could give me some advice what wrong am I doing to obtain access to the device. I have access to BT on VM, as I can list devices from console or settings, within MB3.

My enviroment:

Ubuntu 19.10 on: VirtualBox 6.0.14 inside Windows 10 Education

Notebook MSIGP63 8RE-403XPL

Band is unpaired with MiFit at the moment of connection.

I believe you can help me with this issue.

Comment: can you access bluetooth on Windows? Maybe you have to change some settings in VirtualBox to get access to bluetooth in Windows - see [Enabling Bluetooth in VirtualBox](https://scribles.net/enabling-bluetooth-in-virtualbox/)

Comment: Well I have access to BT on Windows before turning on VM. One more thing I forgot to mention - I'm able to find device (Mi Band) from Bluetooth menu and console in Ubuntu too, the problem is connection to it.

Answer (score 0):

Type this, it should fix the problem

> sudo btmgmt le on

Comment: Type this where? The terminal? Please give more details.